# Cloud Scheduler Not Working With Cloud Run Jobs I think it is my URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Hi I have a Python script running fine in the new Cloud Run Jobs service that GCP have released. What I am having problems with is Cloud Scheduler. - This is cloud run jobs not just cloud run.

I think that perhaps the URL is wrong but I am not sure 100% here are the logs. It seems to be saying that it can't find the job but it has the correct name. Any help would be much appreciated. It is my first time using Cloud Scheduler.

Just so you know the script basically makes an API call to Mouseflow creates a dateframe and sends it directly to bigquery. The script itself is working fine.

This is the python code which as I said is working fine.

````
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
#import schedule
#import time


r = requests.get("https://api-eu.mouseflow.com/websites/e768ed54-c09b-48dc-bf49-beda12697013/pagelist",
auth=HTTPBasicAuth("***************", "*************"))


parsed = json.loads(r.text)
print(json.dumps(parsed['pages'], indent=4, sort_keys=True))


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(parsed['pages'])
    

#df.to_csv('mousedata3.csv')#
df.to_gbq('Mouseflow.Mouseflow_ETL', if_exists='replace', project_id='api-data-pod')
#Sent info to cloud securely#
    
# Time
#schedule.every().day.at("06:30").do(req)
#schedule.every(30).seconds.do(req)
#schedule.every(45).seconds.do(dt)
#schedule.every(5).minutes.do(req)

#while True:
    #schedule.run_pending()
    #time.sleep(1)```
````

This is the Cloud Scheduler URL and log I am using to to call via HTTP.
https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1/namespaces/api-data-pod/jobs/cloudyjoby2:run

`{ "insertId": "rgzvcyf8u3ywd", "jsonPayload": { "status": "NOT_FOUND", "url": "https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1/namespaces/api-data-pod/jobs/cloudyjoby2", "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "targetType": "HTTP", "jobName": "projects/api-data-pod/locations/us-central1/jobs/Mouseflowtest" }, "httpRequest": { "status": 404 }, "resource": { "type": "cloud_scheduler_job", "labels": { "job_id": "Mouseflowtest", "project_id": "api-data-pod", "location": "us-central1" } }, "timestamp": "2022-07-28T15:59:05.356773252Z", "severity": "ERROR", "logName": "projects/api-data-pod/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions", "receiveTimestamp": "2022-07-28T15:59:05.356773252Z" }`

I am guessing it is my URL?

Comment: Did you double check the projectID, job Name and the region?

Comment: Yep, I did, that's the weird thing regions= us-central1, project id= api-data-pod, job = cloudyjoby2. Am I missing something @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: I don't know. Sometime there is a confusion between the project ID and the project name. Try to use the gcloud command, with a `--log-http` to review exactly the API call that is performed and copy it.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere is it just gcloud --log-http ? Do I have to be in a specific directory? I plan on doing the Associate course for gcp but as I figured getting these tasks to run is quite important in terms of passing the Associate course. It's also forcing me to do a lot more advanced stuff with gcp where I mainly worked with big Query before. I'm having a similar problem with a cloud function but a I haven't had a chance to properly trouble shoot that yet. I may be able to get that running in cloud scheduler. Took me a while to get it running in cloud function.

Comment: I'm unable to understand your code. You're not importing Cloud Scheduler and yet you show a Cloud Scheduler error? The URL in the error looks incorrect as it duplicates `run.googleapis.com` which I think should not occur. Your code uses a library called `schedule` and this takes a parameter `req` that is not defined.  You reference a Cloud Run job but only in passing in the question and it doesn't appear in your code.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, schedule and the req parameter is commented out. How am I supposed to import Cloud Scheduler? I have been following every tutorial and I can find. For creating a job and then creating a URL. It's why I am very confused. This code works fine in Cloud Run Jobs and you suggested I use instead of normal Cloud Run. But I have never seen someone import cloud scheduler. Cloud scheduler is not a python module.

Comment: The expectation is that you should provide a minimally-reproducible example of code. It's not useful to post arbitrary code (commented or not). It would be better to post nothing. I'll post an answer that provides some guidance on how to use Cloud Scheduler but this isn't the best forum for posting tutorials.

Comment: I apologize, reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#execute_jobs), it appears your URL is correct

Answer (score 0):

<strike>#### I've not tried this code!</strike>

A good Google search to start is "Google Cloud Scheduler client libraries" and this gets you to:

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/libraries

and for Python:

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/libraries#python

Google has a confusing (!) library strategy. There are historical (**all** Google Cloud Services) libraries called API Client Libraries and there are Cloud Client Libraries for a subset (!!) of Google Cloud (and there are some gRPC libraries).

See [Client libraries explained](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

For the purposes of this discussion (but it's not always the best answer), I encourage you to use the [Cloud Client Library for Cloud Scheduler for Python](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-scheduler/)

```bash
# Constants
BILLING=[YOUR-BILLING]
PROJECT=[YOUR-PROJECT]
REGION=[YOUR-REGION]
ACCOUNT="tester"
JOB="foo"

NUMBER=$(\
  gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(projectNumber)") && echo ${NUMBER}
COMPUTE_ENGINE="${NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
```

The following code below is equivalent to this `gcloud` command:

```bash
ENDPOINT = "run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1"
URI = "https://${REGION}-${ENDPOINT}/namespaces/${PROJECT}/jobs/${JOB}:run"

gcloud scheduler jobs create http ${JOB} \
--description="" \
--location=${REGION} \
--schedule="0 * * * *" \
--uri="${URI}" \
--http-method=post \
--oauth-service-account-email=${COMPUTE_ENGINE} \
--oauth-token-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

```bash
ACCOUNT="tester"
EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

# Random Cloud Run Job image
IMAGE="gcr.io/cloudrun/hello"

# Create Project and enable Billing
gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# Enable Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Run
SERVICES=(
  "cloudscheduler"
  "run"
)
for SERVICE in ${SERVICES[@]}
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

# Create Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# IAM
# https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-scheduler-roles
ROLES=(
  "roles/cloudscheduler.admin"
  "roles/run.invoker"
)
for ROLE in ${ROLES[@]}
do
  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
  --member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
  --role=${ROLE}
done

# ActAs
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${COMPUTE_ENGINE} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser" \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create Cloud Run Job
gcloud beta run jobs create ${JOB} \
--image=${IMAGE} \
--region=us-west1 \
--project=${PROJECT}

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-scheduler

export PROJECT
export NUMBER
export LOCATION=${REGION}
export JOB=${JOB}

python3 main.py
```

Cloud Scheduler supports 3 remote types: App Engine, PubSub and HTTP target. For Cloud Run, we'll use the generic HTTP target. You'll need to provide auth to invoke the Cloud Run Job unless the Job is public.

`main.py`:

```py
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

import os

# Lazy: avoiding programmatically obtaining
project=os.getenv("PROJECT")
number=os.getenv("NUMBER")
location=os.getenv("LOCATION")
job=os.getenv("JOB")

# Unclear whether you need both of these to make the API call
parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}"
# name = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}/jobs/{job}"
name = f"{parent}/jobs/{job}"

description = ""

# Cloud Run Job URL
# See: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#execute_jobs
endpoint = "run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1"
uri = f"https://{location}-{endpoint}/namespaces/{project}/jobs/{job}:run"

service_account_email = f"{number}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

# cron schedule
schedule = "0 * * * *"

client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

rqst = scheduler.v1_types.CreateJobRequest(
    parent=parent,
    job=scheduler_v1.types.Job(
        name=name,
        description=description,
        http_target=scheduler_v1.types.HttpTarget(
            uri=uri,
            http_method=scheduler_v1.types.HttpMethod(
                scheduler_v1.types.HttpMethod.POST,
            ),
            oauth_token=scheduler_v1.types.OAuthToken(
                service_account_email=service_account_email,
            ),
        ),
        schedule=schedule,
    ),
)

resp = client.create_job(request=rqst)
print(resp)
```

Verify

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs list \
--location=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
ID   LOCATION  SCHEDULE (TZ)    TARGET_TYPE  STATE
foo  us-west1  0 * * * * (UTC)  HTTP         ENABLED

gcloud beta run jobs list \
--project=${PROJECT}
   JOB  REGION    LAST RUN AT              CREATED
✔  foo  us-west1  2022-07-30 18:32:20 UTC  2022-07-30 17:19:02 UTC
```

References:

- [Proto Plus](https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest)
- [CreateJobRequest](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudscheduler/latest/google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.CreateJobRequest)
- [Job](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudscheduler/latest/google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.Job)
- [HttpTarget](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudscheduler/latest/google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.HttpTarget)

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin this is a bit confusing. Your explanation is brilliant, but what I don't understand is what is the point in the cloud scheduler GUI tool for Cron jobs if you have to add all that code to run a cron job. None of the tutorials about Cloud Scheduler ever mention having to code the solution. I'm not against it. It just seems like a very important to piece of information that is lacking. Surely just allowing Cron jobs to be written in Linux would be easier than writing python code?

Comment: You can create the Cloud Scheduler job using `gcloud` too [`gcloud scheduler jobs create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create)

Comment: I'll add the equivalent `gcloud scheduler jobs create` to the answer

Comment: You could create a cron job on a linux host to periodically invoke the Cloud Run Job too but then you'd need to ensure that the host were available 24x7. Cloud Scheduler is like Cron-as-a-Service.

Comment: Hi @DazWilKin so is all I need to do run gcloud scheduler jobs list \
--location=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
ID   LOCATION  SCHEDULE (TZ)    TARGET_TYPE  STATE
foo  us-west1  0 * * * * (UTC)  HTTP         ENABLED

gcloud beta run jobs list \
--project=${PROJECT}
   JOB  REGION    LAST RUN AT              CREATED
✔  foo  us-west1  2022-07-30 18:32:20 UTC  2022-07-30 17:19:02 UTC  from the gcp command line, I don't have to import any new modules into my python script?

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin the other question can't this be done by the GUI as if it can't I fail to see the point of the GUI.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin I am the owner of the whole gcp setup so from what I understand I have invoke rights for everything. Could my problems be linked to permissions? I have checked and I seem to have invoke rights.

Comment: Yes, you can do it using Cloud Console too

Comment: Yes, you can run the `gcloud` (CLi) command too but from a Linux shell (no additional imports).

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin I found out something interesting after waiting for the data to change today. I have the python code set up as a cloud function as well as I knew it would give me a URL. But I found the same problem. But although cloud scheduler fails it's actually updating the table in BigQery. I'm curious how it can mark itself as a fail but still actually run a cron job successfully? 
I will have to test if the same thing happens with my Cloud Run Job.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin I have it set to update every 5 minutes for testing purposes though and what I noticed the replaced and loading process takes 3 event and often but not always the first event fails. So that might be why there is a failure? But the table has updated everytime as it was only the first event that failed.